# How to take snapshot of the filesystem in linux (files, their sizes only, not their data)

Tags: linux, backup, snapshot

We need to take a snapshot of your linux server. We don't want to backup the data, just a snapshot we can compare against changes.

Comment: What kind of changes?  Content of files, or just changes in the metadata, like permissions or ownership?

Comment: both, i just need to know a file has been messed around with so we can check to see what's changed

Comment: Then AIDE it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find / -ls > fileinfo.txt
```

But take a look at tripwire and aide, since that seems to be what you are aiming for anyway. Also note that rpm can check files against checksums and for debian based distributions there is debsums.

Comment: Agree. Probably tripwire and aide are what he looks for

Answer (score 2):

i would recommend checking for md5 sums of files, and not just file size. however:

`find / -printf "%h/%f %s\n" > /some/path/filesize` would generate a list of files and their sizes.

you could also do `find / | xargs md5sum 2> /dev/null 1> /some/path/file-md5s` to generate a list of filenames and their md5 sums.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
du <filesystem mount point>
```

it should give you size and file in full location